# SQL Developer eats up my profile space

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I change the location of this directory created by SQL Developer :

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.0.0.13.80
```

I have a very limited space on my roaming profile and each time SQL Developer regenerates files here. Is there I way I can change the location?

Comment: Can we move this to SuperUser please? Does not seem that I've got the rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found it. You need to define an environment variable `JDEV_USER_HOME` and set it to "c:\SOME_DIR"

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://community.oracle.com/message/10143479#10143479), the environment variable to be changed is `IDE_USER_DIR`.

From the post:

> According to documentation, the `IDE_USER_DIR` is picked up automatically if set, so there should be no need for an additional conf file set statement in any recent SQL Developer release.